# How to send gtag conversion event via php?

Tags: php, gtag.js

How to send this gtag conversion event using php? Can't find any examples online. Is this even possible?

```
gtag('event', 'conversion', {
  'send_to': '...',
  'value': 19,
  'currency': 'GBP',
  'transaction_id': '...'
});
```

Comment: Might be tough, and awfully broad as you'd have to dig into the google code to see how it's sent. However, the gtag javascript is minimized, so good luck with that.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to use `gtag` as a PHP function since it is build for JavaScript.

Although it is possible to use PHP to insert it into you HTML. And with your PHP variables populate the data that you need to send to `gtag`.

```
<?php
// Change these variables to what you need them to.
$send_to = 'recipient';
$transaction_id = 20912;
?>

<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
    'send_to': <?php echo $send_to; ?>,
    'value': 19,
    'currency': 'GBP',
    'transaction_id': <?php echo $transaction_id; ?>
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I need to send that event using php not javascript, that was the question ;)

Comment: Ah, my bad. Well that seems like some unexplored territory. I hope you find your answer! :)